# How to change the order of the power options in start menu?

Tags: windows-10, regedit

Is it possible to change the order of the [Power Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRV6D.png) in Windows 10 using the settings or regedit,etc.
I would like the sleep button to come under the shut down button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no way to change the order of the power options.**

You are only able to *enable or disable* power options via `regedit` which can be done by going to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start` and going to an option such as `HideShutDown` or `HideSleep` etc and changing the key named `value` to `1` if you want to disable it, or to `0` if you want to enable it again.